# Compare the same row

Tags: mysql

I have a table - user_tracking - which stores the user_id, purchase sku, and event time_created. Each time a user returns to purchase the original user_id is referenced with a new timestamp:

```
User_ID    Sku             Time_Created
  1       1234          2012-10-01 01:00:00
  2       2345          2012-10-02 02:00:00
  3       6789          2012-10-02 01:00:00
  2       5432          2012-10-04 04:00:00
```

I want to measure the return customer usage, but only for customers that have returned within 7-60 days of initial purchase. Currently my query looks something like:

```
SELECT
  total_purchases.user_id             as user_1_id,
  total_purchases.time_created        as time_1_created,
  total_purchases.total_purchases     as total_original_purchases,
  total_return.user_id                as user_2_id,
  total_return.time_created           as time_2_created,
  total_return.total_return_purchases as total_return_purchases
FROM (SELECT
    user_tracking.user_id                as user_id,
    user_tracking.time_created           as time_created,
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_tracking.sku)    as total_purchases
      FROM user_tracking
      WHERE user_tracking.time_created BETWEEN "2012-10-01 00:00:00"
      AND "2012-10-15 00:00:00") AS total_purchases
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
           user_tracking.user_id                as user_id,
           user_tracking.time_created           as time_created,
           COUNT(DISTINCT user_tracking.sku)    as total_return_purchases
         FROM user_tracking
         WHERE user_tracking.time_created BETWEEN "2012-10-01 00:00:00"
         and "2012-12-15 00:00:00") AS total_return
    ON total_purchases.user_id = total_return.user_id
```

How can I ensure I'm only measuring purchases within 7-60 days with the original user?

Comment: What's the problem with your current query?

Comment: Currently it tracks all purchases regardless of the time interval between - if they have multiple purchases within 7 days it doesn't exclude all, only the first defined. I need a way to ensure that all purchases within the first 7 days are excluded.

Comment: what do you want? Do you want to exclude first 7 days entries then get all other entries within 60 days. am i right or is there something else?

Comment: That's right. Ideally all user_ids will be listed with the original purchase sku, and then the count of return purchases within 7-60 days.

Comment: Can you provide table structures , sample data and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use interval

```
AND datecolumn BETWEEN (datecolumn, INTERVAL 7 DAYS) AND (datecolumn, INTERVAL 60 DAYS)
```

Comment: Can you clarify? Where is this being added and how does this separate out the identical column with each group (original spend and return)?